# ReliabilityContract and IComparer (or other injected code)

Tags: c#, .net, il, reliability

In writing some code to mimic an as-complete-as-possible emulation of System.Array, I have come across something that I find confusing and dangerous.

With the following method signature:

```
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
public static int BinarySearch<T>(T[] array, T value, IComparer<T> comparer)
```

A method is declared with a contract saying that it will definitely not corrupt any state, even itself, if there is a failure.  It also implies that some code external to the contract will be called via the `comparer` value, and `IComparer<T>.Compare` does not require a reliability contract; a call to `comparer.Compare(x,y)` can certainly corrupt state and violate the contract.

How is this valid? I'm not an expert on the uses of constrained execution... will a constrained execution environment inspect the `Compare` method at runtime, and cause an exception if the contract is expected to be enforced? Is this a hole in the reliability contract?

Or, are constrained execution regions CIL voodoo that I should avoid in non-framework code? I want to keep as close as possible behavior to native System.Array, and so I would like to maintain the same `ReliabilityContract` attributes where the underlying implementation supports it; but it seems to me that even the internals can't guarantee the contract, so I am quite puzzled how *I* could guarantee the contract.

Comment: You're not going to get very close to the behaviour of the native System.Array anyway. Array is runtime magic - generic before generics were implemented, magic redirects to pretend arrays are sort-of-generic once generics were implemented... Arrays are voodoo on their own :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, [CER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228973%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)s are a very advanced feature and are used very rarely. Unless you really want your class to be usable in a CER (or if you're not sure what CERs actually are), you shouldn't specify any `ReliabilityContract`.

If you still want to investigate CERs, read Stephen Toub's [*Keep Your Code Running with the Reliability Features of the .NET Framework*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163716.aspx). I think the most relevant part of that article is (emphasis mine):

> Reliability contracts also have some interesting interpretation issues. For example, one of the problems the CLR designers ran into is that most well-implemented methods check their parameters and throw exceptions for input that is not valid. Thus, an approach of simply outlawing all allocations from within CERs would have been next to useless (some methods may also allocate and then recover from any out of memory exceptions). Reliability contracts are an attempt to abstract away that type of detail from the runtime, allowing the code author to clearly state whether callers need to worry about failures, and if so, how much state may need to be thrown away. As a consequence, reliability contracts are considered null and void if the arguments passed to the method are illegal or the method is used incorrectly. Additionally, there may be concepts that aren't easily expressed through the contracts. Imagine a method that accepts an Object as a parameter and calls its Equals method. **This method may be reliable, but only if you pass in an object that has a reliable Equals override. There is currently no built-in way to express that concept.**

I *think* the highlighted section means that `BinarySearch` shouldn't have been marked as `WillNotCorruptState`. Or it's possible that the case with a delegate is more transparent than calling `Equals()` of a passed in `object`, so the attribute is actually okay here.

In any case, I think that to be on the safe side, you shouldn't specify any `ReliabilityContract`s, unless you really know what you're doing and you really need it.